# How to mock a client class executina a request in an integration test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In my microservice I have an endpoint `AppointmentController` which will get the appointments for a specified user. The controller calls the `GetAppointmentsClient` which retrieves the data from some other endpoint.

I am now creating IntegrationTests for `AppointmentController` but I'm having some issues mocking the `GetAppointmentsClient`. It is now actually executing a request which results in an exception.

The `AppointmentControllerIT` test class look like this:

```
public class MantelzorgerControllerIT : WebServerTest
{
    private readonly CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

    public MantelzorgerControllerIT ()
    {
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_WhenAuthorized_ThenOk()
    {
        GetAppointmentsClientMock.Setup(mock =>
            mock.Get(
                It.IsAny<Guid>(),
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(new List<Appointment>());

        var result = await Client.GetAsync(CreateMantelzorgerUrl(_spreekuurIdpId), _cancellationToken);

        result.StatusCode.Should.Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}

public abstract class WebServerTest
{
    internal readonly TestServer Server;

    protected HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

    protected Mock<IGetAppointmentsClient> GetAppointmentsClientMock { get; } 
    = new Mock<IGetAppointmentsClient>();

    public WebServerTest()
    {
        Server = new TestServer(GetAppointmentsClientMock.Object);
        Client = Server.CreateClient();
    }
}

internal class TestServer : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly object[] _dependencyOverrides;

    public TestServer(params object[] dependencyOverrides)
    {
        _dependencyOverrides = dependencyOverrides;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configBuilder) =>
            {
            // Placeholder: replace configuration for test configuration.
                configBuilder.SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json"),
                    optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                // Placeholder: replace services for test services.
                services.AddAuthentication(TestAuthHandler.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>(
                    TestAuthHandler.AuthenticationScheme, options => { });

                AddAuthorizationForTest(services);

                foreach (var dependency in _dependencyOverrides)
                {
                    services.AddSingleton(dependency);
                }
        });
    }
}
public class AppointmentController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGetAppointmentsClient _appointmentsClient;
 
    public AppointmentController(IGetAppointmentsClient appointmentsClient)
    {
        _appointmentsClient) = appointmentsClient;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid clientId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var appointments = await _appointmentsClient.Get(clientId, cancellationToken);

        return Ok(appointments);
    }
}
```

So I attempt to register `GetAppointmentsClientMock` through `_dependencyOverrides` and then mock the `Get` method but I'm probably doing something wrong.
What is the correct way to do this?

EDIT: Added the code of the AppointmentController;

Comment: Can you share the relevant controller code also? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Chetan What I'm trying to do is to create an integrationtest for the AppointmentController.Get endpoint. As you can see in the code, the controller calls the GetAppointmentsClient.Get method which I want to mock. But instead the GetAppointmentsClient.Get method is actually executed and tries to execute the request to the endpoint of our third party supplier which I want to prevent.